# Axios Asynchronous Function Returning The Incorrect Order

Tags: reactjs, sorting, async-await, axios, get

When using the asynchronous function `getProvinces()` on `func initProvinces()` via `axios.get`, the `provinceCities` are not retrieved alphabetically, differing from their order in `func initProvinces()`.

How could I change `getProvinces()` to return the `provinceCities` alphabetically?

**Using Axios To Get The Data With getProvinces():**

```
    export async function getProvinces() {
      const result = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT}/info/provinces`
      );
    
      return result.data;
    }
```

**Golang Function initProvinces() With The Data:**

```
func initProvinces() {

    provinceCities = make(map[string][]string)

    //Anhui
    provinceCities["安徽省"] = []string{"安庆市", "蚌埠市", "亳州市", "巢湖市", "池州市", "滁州市", "阜阳市", "广德市", "合肥市", "淮北市", "淮南市", "黄山市", "界首市", "六安市", "马鞍山市", "明光市", "宁国市", "潜山市", "宿州市", "天长市", "桐城市", "铜陵市", "芜湖市", "无为市", "宣城市"}

    //Beijing
    provinceCities["北京市"] = []string{"北京市"}
...
}
```

*The list of provinces is much larger, and I've just included the first two.*

**The console.log of the data:**

```
(33) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {province: '黑龙江省', cities: Array(33), autoPopulate: false}
1: {province: '天津市', cities: Array(1), autoPopulate: true}
```

Comparison, index 0 is '黑龙江省', whereas it should be "安徽省".

Comment: What order are you referring to? The order of the response data? Can you share what the observed result is and share what you expect the result to be, and also anything you've tried to do to make the code return the expected result?

Comment: @DrewReese, thank you for constructively criticising my question. I've made a lot of changes to help illustrate the issue.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like you need to sort this array of provinces. Hopefully you understand that some non-native speakers/readers (myself included) can't read what the values are to understand why the first element is incorrect. That being said, I guess you can either return the data already sorted from the API, or you can sort it locally in your UI code once it's received.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you have a couple options for sorting the data:

- Return the data already sorted from the API
- Sort it locally in your UI code once it's received

I'm not familiar with GoLang to speak to the sorting on the API side (*though I assume sorting is still a trivial call)*, but here's an example of sorting the response data on the app side in javascript.

Use a custom comparator to compare the `province` property using `String.prototype.localeCompare`. *Note that you may need to also specify the `locales` and `options` arguments to customize the behavior to fit the language you're using.*

```
const compareByProvince = (a, b) => a.province.localeCompare(b.province);

export async function getProvinces() {
  const result = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT}/info/provinces`
  );

  return result.data.sort(compareByProvince);
}
```

- [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Sorting non-ASCII characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sorting_non-ascii_characters)
- [String.prototype.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Answer (score 0):

**Front-end Solution:**
When assigning the data to a prop to be passed down to the `provinces.jsx` file, we were already using `.map()` to get the relevant information into the component's return.

I thus used `.sort()` to sort the information before mapping it. It didn't work when mapping it, then sorting it.

The end line of code looked like this:

```
const PROVINCE_OPTIONS = provinces.sort((x,y)=>x.province.localeCompare(y.province, 'zh-CN')).map((item) => item.province)
```